# exportar datos de datagrid a excel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

tengo un inconveniente al exportar los datos de un datagrid a excel el inconveniente es que siempre me salta el primer registro es decir no lo exporta
si son 85 registros me exporta 84 y no se porque el bucle  esta fallando en esa parte.

aqui mi buque que exporta

```
 Dim columnsCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.Count
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    If i = 0 Then 'pintamos cabecera
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText

                    Else 'pintamos datos

                        hoja_trabajo.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()


                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro pero ciando hacer If i = 0 Then te estas saltando el primer registro y por eso te sale una linea menos.

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                If i = 0 Then 'pintamos cabecera
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells(1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText
                 End If

                    hoja_trabajo.Cells(2 + i, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()

            Next
        Next
```

O también

```
      For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                If i = 0 Then 'pintamos cabecera
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText

                Else 'pintamos datos

                    hoja_trabajo.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i -1).Cells(j).Value.ToString()


                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: remplazando esa linea ahora me quita el ultimo registro

Comment: No estoy seguro si funcione la actualización que puse, perdón pero no tengo forma de probarlo :(

Comment: al parecer el segundo ejemplo si funciono compañero muchas gracias por su colaboración.